# same attribute, different value for xpath

Tags: xpath, syntax, attributes

I'd like to know if it is possible to make xpath with same attribute but different values shorter, than explicitly say @attributeName all the time.
Example - I have two pages with firstName input, in one page it is

```
//*[@name='first']
```

and in the other

```
//*[@name='firstName']
```

. So a shared xpath is

```
//*[@name='first' or @name='firstName']
```

Is there any way to make it shorter like

```
//*[(@name)='first' or 'firstName']
```

I tried different ways of handling that using brackets, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which version of XPath you are using. In XPath 2.0 or later you could write the expression like this:

```xpath
//*[@name = ('first', 'firstName')]
```

The parenthetical expression `('first', 'firstName')` defines a *sequence* of two strings, and the boolean expression `@name = ('first', 'firstName')` is a kind of [*general comparison*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons) in which the value of the `name` attribute is compared to the items in the sequence using the `=` operator, and which returns `true` if the attribute is equal to *any* of the values in the sequence, or `false` if it equals *none* of the values in the sequence.

In XPath 1.0 I don't know of any simpler way to write the expression than the way you've already used. I mean, you *could* use:

```xpath
//*[contains(@name, 'first')]
```

... but that could also catch other values of `@name`, such as `firstAddress`, etc.